# Symfony 3.4 to 4.4 migration break calls methods on doctrine listener

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony4

My listener definition (no autowiring) :

[image: Service definition]

Symfony detect it like that :

[image: Symfony service definition]

I have the two methods in my class, there were working in Symfony 3.4, but now in Symfony 4.4 they aren't called (I get a Symfony error like $this->serviceOne->doSomething() call on null).

Comment: Your service declaration looks good. What if you debug `My\ServiceOne` with the same command ?

Comment: I get a normal service (no autowired, no autoconfigured).
In m y case I have an another calls method on service one and nothing particular for service two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Symfony 4.4 you can't get a private service. The doctrine resolver that we use was using `$this->container->has(xxx)`.
That was working in Symfony 3.4 but no more in Symfony 4.4.